# Using a RealTek Ethernet Switch

Tags: pic, ethernet, microcontroller

I'm starting a project using the Realtek [RTL8305SC](http://realtek.info/pdf/rtl8305sc.pdf) ethernet switch. Does anybody have a good idea of how to use it, some code for it, or even a flow diagram of how it should be used in conjunction with an Ethernet enabled PIC?

Any help would be appreciated! I'm currently wondering what I need to do to get it working with the PIC, specifically the order of events. Do I need to reset the switch before enabling the ethernet in the PIC, or do I enable the ethernet on the PIC while the switch is in reset mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RTL8305SC doesn't require any actual code, but you need to read through it's [datasheet](http://realtek.info/pdf/rtl8305sc.pdf) for a good description of how to wire it up.

In general, connect the output of the PIC's ethernet to one of the RTL8305's ports in a cross-over (or enable auto crossover on the RTL8305). Connect the rest f the RTL8305's ports to ethernet jacks (w/ magnetics).

While I haven't used this particular switch, it's usually easier if you release the switch from reset, then enable the PIC's ethernet core. But if you do things the other way, it will just look like an unplugged cable to the PIC.

Answer (score 1):

Switch is just a switch. You plug ethernet connected device to it and it automagically starts to route packets. It does not matter if the device is a Powerbook, PC or a PIC gadget with ethernet.

Your gadget <---> Switch <---> Intenet

For you gadget to talk to the Intterwebs your PIC gadget of course know how to handle the TCP/IP layer.

Comment: This question is about an embedded ethernet switch controller, not a standalone switch device that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Microchip offer a free licensed TCP/IP stack for certain chips. More information from their website is available on the [TCP/IP Download and Support](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2505&param=en535724) page. This specific page is in the middle of a group of pages discussing PIC and Ethernet connections.